# change the attribute of circles based on multiple selections in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making circles on a Leaflet map and allow users to filter those points through dropdown and slider. The filter choice of the user is stored in these two variables.

```
var fildata_quant = {'depthError':[0.1, 0.3]};
var fildata_category = {'country':['US','IN'],'magType':['ml','md']};
```

Now, I am trying to make a selection function where the user selects the circles from the filtered circles. The selected choice of the user is stored in these two variables.

```
var seldata_quant = {'depthError':[0.1, 0.2]};
var seldata_category = {'country':['US'], 'magType': ['ml']};
```

I am creating and updating my circles(based on filters) using this function -

```
function updateSubset(filterLoad = 0) { 

// getting the filtered data
var arr = geoData;
var filterObjArray = Object.entries(fildata_category);
var filterQuantArray = Object.entries(fildata_quant);
var result = arr.filter(o => filterObjArray.every(([k,v]) => v.includes(o[k])) && filterQuantArray.every(([k,[l,h]]) => o[k] >= l && o[k] <= h));    
var points = pointsG.selectAll("circle")
                          .data(result);

var pointsEnter = points.enter().append("circle")
                        .attr("class", "points");  

points.merge(pointsEnter).attr("r", function(d) { return sizeScale(d[size_name]); })
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.4)
      .style("fill", function(d){ return ordinalScale(d[color_name]);});

selectionStroke(result, seldata_category,seldata_quant);
map.on('zoomend', updateLayers);
updateLayers();

points.exit().remove();  
}
```

I want to add black stroke to my selected circles among the filtered ones to make a distinction. and this is what I wrote---

```
function selectionStroke(data, seldata_category,seldata_quant){
    var selectedObjArray = Object.entries(seldata_category);
    var selectedQuantArray = Object.entries(seldata_quant);
    var selectedData = data.filter(o => selectedObjArray.every(([k,v]) => v.includes(o[k])) && selectedQuantArray.every(([k,[l,h]]) => o[k] >= l && o[k] <= h));

    var selectedCircles = d3.selectAll('.points').data(selectedData).style('stroke-width',2).style("stroke", "black");}
```

This work with seldata_quant alone. but does not work with seldata_category alone or in combination with seldata_quant. I don't where am I going wrong

Comment: filter the selection **not** the data, do not bind the data.

Comment: Ok. But how do I filter on multiple values based on an object?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the selection

```
var selectedCircles = d3.selectAll('.points').filter( o => {
      return selectedObjArray.every(([k,v]) => v.includes(o[k])) && 
        selectedQuantArray.every(([k,[l,h]]) => o[k] >= l && o[k] <= h);
    })
    .style('stroke-width',2)
    .style("stroke", "black");
```

Comment: Thanks! But It does not work at all. Neither does it throw an error.

Comment: @KuhuGupta: do you expect me to rebuild your application and try to implement your requirement and then give you the source code. I have only the few lousy lines of code you give me.

Comment: @KuhuGupta: Javascript should be **strict** by default, update answer